# using items from php array to change css

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

UPDATE: I should add the overall goal is to change the background of a cell based on the 1st query and the border based on the second query then when the beacon stops being pulled in on the 1st query the background goes back to grey

I am trying to use data pulled in from mysql to change the background of table cells, after some modification to my code it no longer works all though the data is still being passed through via Ajax using code below:
before the modification i only used 1 array but since adding 2 arrays as an outer array i can't get it to work, also i i add an item to the console log i just get undefined e.g. item.beacon would normally return a number instead it returns undefined in the console log although it is in the array.

data
I have included the data as a picture to save using to much text

html

```
 <script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        $.each(response, function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${beacon}`).css('background-color', location).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });


        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                console.log(beacon);
                //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $(`td.${beacon}`).css('background-color', location).toggleClass('coloured');
            });
        });

    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});
</script>
```

php

```
#   header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');

$sql1 = 'SELECT 
  * 
  FROM
(SELECT
  beacon,location,date,
  COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 40 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;';
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$rows1 = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sql2 = "SELECT beacon,location,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)), '%i.%s') 
AS `delivery_avg` 
FROM `test`.`test` 
where date = CURDATE()
and time > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
group by beacon";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$rows2 = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


$result = array(
'query1' => $rows1,
'query2' => $rows2,
);

echo json_encode($result);

$conn->close();
```

[image: Snapshot of the Data Array]

Comment: In your `each()` loops, you need to use `response.query1` and `response.query2`, not `response`.

Comment: thank you chris that did resolve it to a point how can i include both response.query1 and 2 in the function/ajax call as if i include both a get b.call is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's example code that should solve this:

```
$.getJSON('php/test.php', function(response) {
    $.each(response.query1, function(index, item) {
        console.log(item);
        // use first array's item.beacon, item.location, etc.
    });
    $.each(response.query2, function(index, item) {
        console.log(item);
        // use second array's item.beacon, item.location, etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry i should have added  the overall goal is to change the background of a cell based on the 1st query and the border based on the second query then when the beacon stops being pulled in on the 1st query the background goes back to grey

Comment: How to do that is a separate question though, isn't it? My answer shows how to load and use both arrays.